# React / Redux and Swagger client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, swagger

I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure a React / Redux app that will primarily use a [swagger client](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js) for api access.

The problem is I'm not entirely sure where to store a reference to the swagger client. After logging in and obtaining a JWT auth token, I need to tell all subsequent requests to add the authorize header. With axios this is trivial because it persists it's headers until told otherwise. It doesn't appear the swagger client does this. So ideally, I would create a swagger client once upon login, add the header info and just reference it for all future requests (that way too it only fetches the schema json once in a single page application).

Since I'm doing this in the context of an action, would it be best to store the Swagger client in the Redux store (and how would I accomplish that)? Or would I create a static instance of it outside of Redux?

```
// app init
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
export const swaggerClient = { instance: authService.createFromState().then(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
       <Provider store={store}></Provider>
       ...
    );
});
```

do some login stuff, create swagger client:

```
// redux action
import { swaggerClient } from '../index';
// ... do login, get bearerToken
Swagger({
    url: 'https://localhost/swagger/v1/swagger.json',
    requestInterceptor(req) {
      req.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${bearerToken}`;
      return req;
    }
}).then((client) => {
    // store reference for all future ajax calls
    swaggerClient.instance = client;
});
```

and in case the page is refreshed, we need to rebuild the swagger client from the bearerToken in local storage

```
// authService
import { swaggerClient } from '../index';
function createFromState() {
  // if authentication is known from localstorage, we can rebuild
  // a swagger client
  if(isAuthenticated()) {
    const authentication = getAuthentication();
    return Swagger({
      url: 'https://localhost/swagger/v1/swagger.json',
      requestInterceptor(req) {
        req.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${authentication.bearerToken}`;
        return req;
      }
    }).then((client) => {
      swaggerClient.instance = client;
      return client;
    });
  }
}
```

I'm a little confused if this is the right direction, probably a newbie question. Having to wait for the swagger client to load while restoring from localstorage seems a kinda crazy way to do this (to prevent race conditions on future calls).

Comment: You might get a faster/better answer if you ask in the [Swagger JS repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues).